# mariadb.InterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: python, mariadb, database-cursor

I am able to call `cnxn.commit()` whenever a cursor has data however when the cursor is empty it throws `cnxn.commit() mariadb.InterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`
using
**cursor.execute("call getNames")**

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I should not call stored procedure but rather pass the query manually like `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM names")`